# Problemas para acessar uma web api em um projeto Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin-forms

Na minha primeira tela do meu `app mobile` que estou fazendo é a tela de *Login*, porém sempre que tento logar o retorno é

> StatusCode: 404,
>
> ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found'

Já confirmei e a `uri` está correta, acesso via *postman* normalmente, comecei a desconfiar que é alguma coisa que falte configurar no projeto ou manifesto do `app`, já testei o projeto *Android* e `UWP`, todos dão o mesmo problema.

O que me deu essa certeza é que eu criei um `console app` só pra testar o acesso a `api`, tudo funciona normalmente, segue o código:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace app1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var url = "https://api.dominio.com.br/login";
            var userName = "fulano@gmail.com";
            var password = "12345678";

            var token = GetToken(url, userName, password);
        }

        static string GetToken(string url, string userName, string password)
        {
            var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "username", userName ),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string> ( "password", password )
                    };
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
            
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
                JObject o = JObject.Parse(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                return (string)o["token"];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Como posso resolver este problema ?

A pedidos vou colocar o código que não está funcionando, apesar que é o mesmo do código acima:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AppMobile.Services
{
    public class Auth : IAuthenticate
    {
        const string Url = "https://api.dominio.com.br/Login";
        
        public async Task<string> GetToken(string user, string pass)
        {
            var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "username", user ),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string> ( "password", pass )
            };
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await client.PostAsync(Url, content);
                JObject obj = JObject.Parse(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                var token = (string)obj["token"];
                
                return token;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Se entendi bem, esse console está funcionando, correto? Se sim, precisamos do código que não está funcionando para averiguarmos o motivo. Se possível, você poderia [edit] sua pergunta e adicione essas informações?

Comment: Tenta colocar o content assim, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pairs).

Comment: @Randrade, coloquei o código que pediu.

Comment: Você especificou a permissão do manifest no android para autorizar acesso a internet ? 
android.permission.INTERNET

Comment: Tente o seguinte, no seu projeto `Android - MainActivity.cs` adicione no ínicio método `OnCreate` o código `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
            (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;` Caso funcione adiciono como resposta.

Comment: @JuniorPorfirio, eu acessei o manifest e não encontrei essa opção, mas pelo que entendi nesse link aqui é uma permissão que já está incluso:

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/general/projects/add_permissions_to_android_manifest/

Comment: @MarcoViniciusSoaresDalalba, Se eu fizer isso o content vai ser um tipo string, o PostAsync não recebe isso, recebe um HttpContent, não vai funcionar...

Comment: Sim está inclusa para autorizar no android manifest. Para isto você deve no VS clicar com o botão direito do projeto Droid e ir em propriedades -> Android Manifest e habilitar o check INTERNET.

Comment: @rubStackOverflow, coloquei o código e deu na mesma, nada mudou.

Comment: @rhgm você conseguiu realizar a configuração no Android Manifest e testar a aplicação ?

Comment: @JuniorPorfirio, já acessei o Android Manifest e não encontrei essa opção, mas eu editei o **AndroidManifest.xml** e adicionei:
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` 
Mesmo assim nada feito, estou tendo o mesmo problema.

Comment: @rhgm, tenta colocar o resultado de string em uma variável com await. ex: var stringresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); ou retirar async para testar e chamar direto no result como fez na console.

Comment: @JuniorPorfirio é a mesma mensagem de erro que já tinha informado `"{\"statusCode\":404,\"error\":\"Not Found\"}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver alterando o post para não rodar de forma assíncrona:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(Url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Por isso funcionava na aplicação console, lá estava síncrono. Ainda não encontrei nada na documentação que explique melhor o porque disso, deveria funcionar de forma assíncrona...